# How to pick a property name in objects that contain 2 property names (and one is constant)?

Tags: javascript

I have these objects:

```
{id: 74856, dog: "value"}

{id: 756387, cat: "value"}

{car: "value", id: 098094}

{phone: "value", id: 90876}
```

I know that each object has 2 properties and that one of them is "id".  How do I pick the other property name in each object?  (I want to get the result "dog" for the first one, "cat" for the second one, "car" for the third one and "phone" for the last one.)

**EDIT:  The use of lodash is not mandatory if not necessary.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all keys using `Object.keys` and erase 'id'.

```js
var v1 = {id: 74856, dog: "value"};

var v2 = {id: 756387, cat: "value"};

var v3 = {car: "value", id: 098094};

var v4 = {phone: "value", id: 90876};

Object.keys(v1).map(function(key){
  if(key != 'id')
  console.log(key);
})
Object.keys(v2).map(function(key){
  if(key != 'id')
  console.log(key);
})
Object.keys(v3).map(function(key){
  if(key != 'id')
  console.log(key);
})
Object.keys(v4).map(function(key){
  if(key != 'id')
  console.log(key);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns the first object member that is not named "id" (in ES6)

```js
let v1 = {id: 74856, dog: "value"};
let v2 = {id: 756387, cat: "value"};
let v3 = {car: "value", id: 98094};
let v4 = {phone: "value", id: 90876};

const excludeIdKey = (key) => key !== "id" ? key : null;

// will return "dog"
console.log(Object.keys(v1).find(excludeIdKey));
// will return "cat"
console.log(Object.keys(v2).find(excludeIdKey));
// will return "car"
console.log(Object.keys(v3).find(excludeIdKey));
// will return "phone"
console.log(Object.keys(v4).find(excludeIdKey));
```